# How Do I Insert Dynamically Created Textbox Values To Database

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code to create dynamical textboxes..I want to insert those values to database

I need to insert the dynamically created textbox values to database.how can i do that..i am new to asp.net

Markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="300px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Remove the session when first time page loads.
        Session.Remove("clicks");
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowCount = 0;

    //initialize a session.
    rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["clicks"]);

    rowCount++;

    //In each button clic save the numbers into the session.
    Session["clicks"] = rowCount;

    //Create the textboxes and labels each time the button is clicked.
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        TextBox TxtBoxU = new TextBox();          
        Label lblU = new Label();          
        TxtBoxU.ID = "TextBoxU" + i.ToString();            
        lblU.ID = "LabelU" + i.ToString();         
        lblU.Text = "Category Name " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : ";

        //Add the labels and textboxes to the Panel.
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lblU);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(TxtBoxU);
    }
}
```

Comment: What database are you using, and how are you communicating with it?

Comment: I am using ms sql server database..

Comment: my table name is Category and fields are CategoryID,CategoryName

Comment: I strongly against generating dynamic controls in ASP.NET web forms app, because it is always a pain to keep them during postbacks. If you really need to provide such features, then move on to ASP.NET MVC or even ASP.NET MVC SPA, life will easier and your code is manageable

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to acces the value of textbox, through this you can easily access the value.
   and I hompe thant u know how to insert data into data base.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                string OptionID = "TextBoxU" + i;
                TextBox tb = (TextBox)Panel1.FindControl(OptionID);

             /******** USe the tb.Text value to get 
                    the value and then store it into Database**********/
            }
```

Comment: I got an error  ...Object reference not set to an instance of oblect...pls help

Comment: U have to add dynamic controls in each post back so...add the controls in PageLoad then only it will be accessible in buttonclick.

Comment: but i create dynamic textbox in add button click

Comment: Put the entire code(for Adding dynamic Controls) of button click in a method and call that method from button click and From pageLoad.

Comment: thanks Kumod....Can you pls run the above code...if i enter value to the textbox and add another textbox the above value is lost...